aws s3 PreSignedUrl file upload status
I upload photos using PreSignedUrl without using the aws s3 upload ID. Is there a way to check the upload status?

A pre-signed URL simply grants permission to perform an upload within the specified restrictions (eg where, how big). Any upload that is performed is unrelated to the pre-signed URL itself. Think of it like the pre-signed URL allowing a door to be opened, but it doesn't care about how many people enter through the door way as long as it was authorised to be open. If you want to know when an object is uploaded, you can either check for the presence of an object or use S3 Events to trigger something when an upload occurs.
